# How to get CSV values using sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, xamarin

[image: ![csdcdscsdcds]

I want

[image]

How to get this CSV Values in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite supports a `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT
    ModifierId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ModifierOptionName) AS OptionsCSV
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    ModifierId = 2
GROUP BY
    ModifierId;
```

### Demo

Note: It is not clear why you expect `Mod2` for the modifier name, when the three records being aggregated all have different modifier names.  If you really expect this, you should explain the logic behind it.